# Java SAX ContentHandler to create new objects for every root node

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am using SAX to parse some XML. Let's say I have the following XML document:

```
<queue>
   <element A> 1 </element A>
   <element B> 2 </element B>
</queue>
<queue>
   <element A> 1 </element A>
   <element B> 2 </element B>
</queue>
<queue>
   <element A> 1 </element A>
   <element B> 2 </element B>
</queue>
```

And I also have an Elements class:

```
public static Elements {

  String element;

  public Elements() {

  }

  public void setElement(String element){
     this.element = element;
  }

  public String getElement(){
     return element;
  }

}
```

I am looking to write a ContentHandler that follows the following algorithm:

```
Vector v;
for every <queue> root node {
   Element element = new Element();

   for every <element> child node{
      element.setElement(value of current element);
   }
   v.addElement(element);
}
```

So, I want to create a bunch of Element objects and add each to a vector...with each Element object containing its own String values (from the child nodes found within the root nodes.

I know how to parse out the elements and all of those details, but can someone show me a sample of how to structure my ContentHandler to allow for the above algorithm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not write the handler with loop as you suggested. It's really event-based, so you need to keep track of the `currentQueue` and `currentElement` yourself in your handler. Beware also that `characters` may be called more than once per tag (there are other questions about this point).

So here is a very rough sketch:

```
Queue currentQueue;
Element currentElement;

startElement(node){
  if( node is queue )
     currentQueue = new Queue();
  else if( node is element )
     currentElement = new Element(); 
}

characters( chars ) {
  currentElement.setName( chars );
}

endElement(node){
  if( node is queue )
     currentQueue = null;
  else if( node is element ) {
     currentQueue.add( currentElement ); <-- that's the important part
     currentElement = null; 
  }
}
```